# Why does indexPathForItemAtPoint() not work for 6plus?

Tags: swift

The way I have my app set up is that each phone size has its own storyboard. For each phone size, I call the function below in the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating() delegate, which finds the centre cell index, and then with this index, centre aligns it. But for the iPhone 6 plus, it always returns nil, and I have no idea why. I checked how the view is set up in the storyboard, and it is all the same. Any one have an idea on how i can solve this problem or why it's happening?

I'm using this function to find the centre cell:

```
private func findCenterIndex() -> NSIndexPath? {
    let collectionOrigin = collectionView.bounds.origin

    let collectionWidth = collectionView.bounds.width

    var centerPoint: CGPoint!
    var newX: CGFloat!
    if collectionOrigin.x > 0 {
        newX = collectionOrigin.x + collectionWidth / 2
        centerPoint = CGPoint(x: newX, y: collectionOrigin.y)
    }
    else {
        newX = collectionWidth / 2
        centerPoint = CGPoint(x: newX, y: collectionOrigin.y)
    }

    let index = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(centerPoint)

    return index
}
```

Comment: *"each phone size has its own storyboard"* - you do know about size classes!?

Comment: @luk2302 not really, I'm just now understanding the fundamentals of auto layout.

Comment: @luk2302 besides that, what do you think might be causing this problem? it's working for every phone size but the 6 plus, which doesn't make any sense.